# Microsoft Academic API, Knowledge graph search -- error 500/503

Tags: web-services, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the graph search method of the Microsoft Academic API to retrieve paper information using the following query:

```
POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/graph/search?mode=json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: my-api-key

{  
    "path": "/paper",
    "paper": {  
        "select": [  
            "PublishYear",
            "CitationCount",
            "ConferenceSeriesID",
            "JournalID",
            "AuthorIDs",
            "AffiliationIDs",
            "AuthorSequenceNumbers",
            "OriginalAffiliations",
            "NormalizedAffiliations",
            "Keywords",
            "FieldOfStudyIDs",
            "ReferenceIDs",
            "CitationIDs",
            "OriginalTitle",
            "NormalizedTitle",
            "DOI",
            "OriginalVenue",
            "NormalizedVenue"
        ],
        "type": "Paper",
        "id": [2059999322, 1993355715, ...]
    }
}
```

For this query, I'm getting one of three responses: 200 OK, 500 internal error, or 503 unavailable (same query and same list of IDs). I just tried to run this query (with the two IDs I listed in the example) five times, out of that, I got 3 correct responses, and 2 errors. Is there something in my request that's causing this or is this an error in the service?

My second question is, is there a limit on how many IDs can I submit in one query? I tried to look for this information on the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/home), but couldn't find anything (just a rate limit in terms of how many queries can be sent per time, but nothing related to query size).

---

EDIT:
Response I'm getting with error 500 (using the query above):

```
{
    'Error': 
    {
        'Message': 'Something went wrong, if the error continue please contact us', 
        'Code': 'InternalError'
    }
}
```

Response that comes with error 503 is empty for me.

Comment: "For this query, I'm getting one of three responses: 200 OK, 500 internal error, or 503 unavailable (same query and same list of IDs)."
Technically the query supplied does not generate the error. 

The error occurs by using 'incorrect' data withheld from the question.

Comment: That's not exactly true. The two IDs I supplied in the question were failing for me about 1/3 of times (and still are when I try to run the query again), I've mentioned that in the question. It is the same two IDs I was testing from the beginning. I don't think you downvoted my question fairly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what the problem is. In case anyone ever has the same issue, it seems it's certain IDs that return an error. I narrowed my set of ~150k IDs to 20 which always fail. The trouble is if an erroneous ID gets mixed in a large batch of IDs which are fine, the whole request fails.